# systemd with python, Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

Tags: python, linux, command-line, systemd

I have a `custom_start.service` file in `/etc/systemd/system` folder

```
[Unit]
Description=System Logging Service

[Service]
User=ABC
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 -c "import os;os.system('cd /home/ABC/Desktop;gnome-terminal -e \"bash -c ./efg\"')"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I have started this service by `systemctl start custom_start.service`.

Upon running `systemctl status custom_start.service`.

The following output came:

```
● custom_start.service - System Logging Service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/custom_start.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Feb 19 15:58:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started System Logging Service.
Feb 19 15:58:00 localhost.localdomain python3[6756]: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Feb 19 15:58:00 localhost.localdomain python3[6756]: # Option “-e” is deprecated and might be removed in a later version of gnome-terminal.
Feb 19 15:58:00 localhost.localdomain python3[6756]: # Use “-- ” to terminate the options and put the command line to execute after it.
Feb 19 15:58:00 localhost.localdomain python3[6756]: # Failed to parse arguments: Cannot open display:
```

How can I make the service active by resolving the above errors.

The command

```
python3 -c "import os;os.system('cd /home/ABC/Desktop;gnome-terminal -e \"bash -c ./efg\"')"
```

is working fine from terminal.

The program `efg` is accessing ethernet.

`systemctl enable custom_start.service` is doing nothing at bootup.
OS is redhat 8.2

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because as the systemd tag states: systemd questions should be for *programming questions* using systemd or its libraries. Questions about *configuring the daemon* (including writing unit files) are better directed to [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com). Please delete this.

Comment: Unable to delete. Better close

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using Python to start a terminal within your job, when you should presumably only be starting the terminal within your job? Furthermore, there's no desktop a gnome-terminal could start on.

```
[Service]
User=ABC
WorkingDirectory=/home/ABC/Desktop
ExecStart=bash -c ./efg
```

would probably be closer to what you want.

I'll also note that "System Logging Service" sounds awfully suspect.

Comment: Will this open a new command window on bootup and run `efg` in the opened command window?

Comment: I'll also note that "System Logging Service" sounds awfully suspect. - I have cloned a service file from system folder. Forgot to change the name.